# Can't Access Pods(Swift + Objc) inside framework target

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, chat

I am using a ProjectB inside ProjectA, which means I have dragged and Dropped projectB inside ProjectA, I have installed Pods for both Project In ProjectA and I can access them in ProjectB also, Now the problem is I have one framework inside ProjectB which is ChatSecureCore, now I also want to access some pod inside this framework like -: YapDatase, Mantle and other all these are objective C module, but I can't access them , It says "could not build Objective-C module 'ChatSecureCore".

Now I want to ask how can I access OBJC module fro this framework even if try to install swift pod it won't accept that also while importing let me show you the Podfile code of ProjectB

```
  install! 'cocoapods', :deterministic_uuids => false

# Blocked on https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/1105
#, :generate_multiple_pod_projects => true

platform :ios, "12.0"

use_modular_headers!
inhibit_all_warnings!

source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'


  target 'ChatSecureCore' do
    pod 'FSPagerView'
      # https://github.com/zxingify/zxingify-objc/pull/491
     #pod 'ZXingObjC/QRCode', :git => 'https://github.com/ChatSecure/ZXingObjC.git', :branch => 'fix-catalyst'

     # https://github.com/sqlcipher/sqlcipher/pull/342
     pod 'SQLCipher', :git => 'https://github.com/ChatSecure/sqlcipher.git', :branch => 'fix-catalyst'

     pod 'ParkedTextField', :git => 'https://github.com/gmertk/ParkedTextField.git', :commit => 'a3800e3' # Swift 4.2
     pod 'JSQMessagesViewController', :path => 'Submodules/JSQMessagesViewController/JSQMessagesViewController.podspec'

     pod 'LumberjackConsole', :path => 'Submodules/LumberjackConsole/LumberjackConsole.podspec'

     # Network
     #pod 'CPAProxy', :path => 'Submodules/CPAProxy/CPAProxy.podspec'
     pod 'XMPPFramework/Swift', :path => 'Submodules/XMPPFramework/XMPPFramework.podspec'

     pod 'ChatSecure-Push-iOS', :path => 'Submodules/ChatSecure-Push-iOS/ChatSecure-Push-iOS.podspec'

     # Waiting on merge https://github.com/yapstudios/YapDatabase/pull/492
     pod 'YapDatabase/SQLCipher', :path => 'Submodules/YapDatabase/YapDatabase.podspec'
     pod 'Mantle', :podspec => 'Podspecs/Mantle.podspec.json'

     # The upstream 1.3.2 has a regression https://github.com/ChatSecure/ChatSecure-iOS/issues/1075
     pod 'libsqlfs/SQLCipher', :path => 'Submodules/libsqlfs/libsqlfs.podspec'

     pod 'IOCipher/GCDWebServer', :path => 'Submodules/IOCipher/IOCipher.podspec'
     pod 'YapTaskQueue/SQLCipher', :path => 'Submodules/YapTaskQueue/YapTaskQueue.podspec'

     # Crypto
     pod 'SignalProtocolObjC', :path => 'Submodules/SignalProtocol-ObjC/SignalProtocolObjC.podspec'
     #pod 'OTRKit', :path => 'Submodules/OTRKit/OTRKit.podspec'

     #pod 'ChatSecureCore', :path => 'ChatSecureCore.podspec'
     pod 'OTRAssets', :path => 'OTRAssets.podspec'
  end


post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
        target.build_configurations.each do |config|
            config.build_settings['ALWAYS_EMBED_SWIFT_STANDARD_LIBRARIES'] = '$(inherited)'
             config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"
        end
    end
end
```

But the pod I have imported in Project I can access them even inside framework specially swift Modules, I just want to build this Framework need assistance, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should add an **Import** statement with the relevant framework name in your ***[appName]*-Bridging-Header.h** file:

```
#import "Mantle.h"
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but, I am using a working project inside another working project and there is a framework inside 2nd project and framework named ChatSecureCore I can't access pods there even via bridge header, if I see in  "other linker flags" and "Framework search Path" I can see all pods there, but can't import pods